# How to automate clicking confirmation pop-up using geb?

Tags: groovy, spock, geb, ui-testing

I'm trying to automate a web application's ui-tests by using **Groovy, Maven, Geb** and **Spock**. I've a page that shows confirmation pop-up to ask user *"Are you sure? -Yes -No"* after clicking a button on  the page. I am able to click the button on the page and I also need to click to "Yes" button which is in the pop-up window. When I inspect the "Yes" button on Google Chrome it looks available, so that I used its name like this on page:

**MyPage.groovy**

```
import geb.Page

class page extends Page{
    static url = "myPage"
    static at = { waitFor { title == "My Page" }}

    static content =
    {
        confirmBtn {$("input[value*='Confirm']")}
        yesBtn {$("input[value*='Yes']")}
    }
}
```

This is what I tried to click "Yes":

**MySpec.groovy**

```
import geb.spock.GebSpec
import MyPage

    class MySpec extends GebSpec{
        def "Confirm"(){
            given:
            def page = to MyPage

            when:
            go MyPage
            page.confirmBtn.click()
            yesBtn.click()

            then:
            ...
        }
    }
```

As a result it gives me the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

How can I click that "Yes" button, do you have any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I debugged the code by adding the following lines before clicking the button:

```
waitFor { yesBtn.isEnabled() }
println "isDisplayed: " + yesBtn.isDisplayed()
println "isEnabled: " + yesBtn.isEnabled()
```

But whether I *waitFor button to get enabled or displayed* or not it always prints:

```
isDisplayed: false
isEnabled: true
```

And after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683330/general-problems-with-geb-staleelementreferenceexception-wait-timeouts) I got the idea that dom needs to get refreshed somehow.

Comment: Have you tried `yesBtn(required:false) { $("input[value*='Yes']") }`?

Comment: @tim_yates After your comment I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: In MySpec.groovy replace:
yesBtn.click()
for:
waitFor { yesBtn.click() }

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it didn't work as well @jripoll

Comment: @tim_yates I'm sorry it worked. It wasn't working because there were several elements with the same value that I wasn't aware of it at the first look. It would be good if you add your comment as an answer.

Comment: @KutluhanMetin done :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the button will not be there when the page is first loaded, [you need to inform Geb of this fact](http://www.gebish.org/manual/0.7.0/pages.html#required) by passing `required: false` like so:

```
yesBtn(required:false) { $("input[value*='Yes']") }
```